# Observe errors in PassthroughSubject in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Let's say I have the following `PassthroughSubject`, somewhere in an `ObservableObject`:

```swift
@Published var errorOccured = PassthroughSubject<(), Error>()
```

I send an error to it with:

```swift
self.errorOccured.send(completion: .failure(error))
```

How can I be notified in a `View` whenever an error occurs? I know that with `onReceive` I can be notified of values, but I am interested in errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are emitting a completion event so you only get to emit an error once using the method you have outlined. If you were to handle the completion event within SwiftUI, your UI would be frozen afterwords. This is not likely what you want, and I don't think the library provides such a method. Consider using a `PassthroughSubject<Error, Never>` instead.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks!